# func not executed inside if statement swift

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to fetch data from firestore for certain user and what i mean here is if there is a user his name is Mark and he logged in to his account i want to fetch **MarkCollection** from the Firestore so i decided to use if statement but it doesn't work . here in the first example i can fetch the data but i want this data to be displayed for the user Mark only and in the second Example i used if statement but the problem is **loadData1()** cannot execute inside if statement.

**First Example:**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class orderTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {



@IBOutlet var userName: UITextField!

var db: Firestore!
var phone = [String]()
var reciept = [String]()
var price = [String]()
var amount = [String]()
var Area = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    loadData1()
}


func loadData1() {
    
    db.collection("markCollection").getDocuments() {
        
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err
        
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                
                self.Area.append(document.get("area") as? String ?? "")
                self.phone.append(document.get("phone") as? String ?? "")
                self.reciept.append(document.get("reciept") as? String ?? "")
                self.price.append(document.get("total price") as? String ?? "")
                self.amount.append(document.get("amount") as? String ?? "")
            }
        }
        self.order.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

and here is the problem when i use the if statement , the loadData1() func cannot execute
here is the code for Example 2:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

    class orderTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet var userName: UITextField!
    
    var db: Firestore!
    var phone = [String]()
    var reciept = [String]()
    var price = [String]()
    var amount = [String]()
    var Area = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if userName.text == "Mark" {
         loadData1()
   
        }
  
        
    }
    
    
    func loadData1() {
        
        db.collection("markCollection").getDocuments() {
            
            (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let err = err
            
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
            }
            else
            {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    
                    self.Area.append(document.get("area") as? String ?? "")
                    self.phone.append(document.get("phone") as? String ?? "")
                    self.reciept.append(document.get("reciept") as? String ?? "")
                    self.price.append(document.get("total price") as? String ?? "")
                    self.amount.append(document.get("amount") as? String ?? "")
                }
            }
            self.order.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YONj.png

Comment: confirm that the userName field is linked. (in Xcode, is the circle beside the definition empty or filled?).

Comment: its filled with white

Comment: so not connected. connect the variable to the uitextfield in the interface file.

Comment: @johnelemans i connect it and it didn't work

Comment: show us the value of the text field in the debugger.

Comment: @johnelemans there is no error in the debugger area but it can not execute the function

Comment: you're calling function loadData1 in viewDidLoad method, that mean the text is not set by '''Mark' yet

Comment: ok i want to call this function if the text set to "Mark" how can i do it ?

Comment: as i said, *show* us the value of the text field in the debugger.

Comment: @johnelemans i updated the post , please check the picture

Answer (score 0):

if you do not set a text "Mark" as a default text to the textField, it is nil at the moment that view cycle is in "ViewDidLoad". When a user enters something by using the keyboard, it happens in a different cycle.

You should check `if userName.text == "Mark"` when the user taps "done" button in the keyboard, or by checking in TextFields delegates while the user is typing.

to check the user input;

you can add this in viewDidLoad;

```
userName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)),
                              for: .editingChanged)
```

and then, in view controller;

```
@objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print(textField.text) // so that you can see whether you can successfully connect the outlet. if nothing prints, it means that you could not connect it properly.
    if textField.text = "Mark" {
     loadData1()
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried with textfieldDidChange but it doesn't work

Comment: did you try to print the text in the textfield. What does "textfieldDidChange" method print when you type something? Does it print "Mark"?

Comment: I also tried the edited code that you shared but the function not executed !